# varias chaves estrangeiras SQL

Tags: chave-estrangeira, chave-primária

Tenho a seguinte tabela: itens (ref) o atributo "ref" como chave primaria da tabela, pode ter associada varias chaves secundarias em outras tabelas [ex:tabela1(ref) e tabela2(ref) sendo "ref" a chave secundaria das respectivas tabelas]?

Comment: Sim, pode ter..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Um breve resumo**

As Chave primárias e estrangeiras são dois tipos de restrições que podem ser usadas para impor integridade de dados nas tabelas.
Geralmente, uma tabela tem uma coluna ou uma combinação de colunas que contém valores que identificam exclusivamente cada linha na tabela (*identity*). Como as restrições PRIMARY KEY garantem dados exclusivos, elas são frequentemente definidas como uma coluna de identidade.

Essa identidade é utilizada nas demais tabelas (chave estrangeira) para classificar os registros que "pertencem" à tabela primária.

Observe o modelo abaixo e veja que é possível SIM definir em quantas for necessário:

```
tbl_usuarios
    PK id_usuarios numero identity---+
       nome texto                    |
                                     |
tbl_materias                         |
    PK id_materias numero identity---͡ -+
       descricao texto               | |
    FK id_usuarios-------------------◄ | 
                                     | |
tbl_faltas                           | |
    PK id_faltas numero identity     | |
       dataRef data                  | |
    FK id_usuarios-------------------◄ |
                                     | |
tbl_notas                            | |
    PK id_notas numero identity      | |
    FK id_materias numero------------͡ -◄
    nota numero                      |
    FK id_usuarios-------------------◄
                                     |
tbl_eventos                          |
    PK id_eventos numero identity    |
       dataRef data                  |
    FK tiposEvento numero            |
    FK id_usuarios-------------------◄

tbl_tiposEvento
    PK id_tiposEvento numero identity
    descricao texto
```

[Restrições de chave primária e chave estrangeira](https://msdn.microsoft.com/pt-br/library/ms179610.aspx)